# How to return both data field and errors field with Graphql-kotlin query

Tags: kotlin, graphql

I am working on one server that resolve GraphQL queries. I used the graphql-kotlin library: https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin.

I defined three resolve functions(could be viewed as three fields): getxxx(arguments...), getTarget(arguments...) and getSource(arguments...).

The problem is if one of my queried field failed, I will only get the 'errors' field. All other successful executed results(data) are dropped.
If I try to catch the exception for the failed field, then I will not get the 'error' field at last.

This is the image that had exception and dropped all fetched data:
[image: This is the image that had exception and dropped all fetched data]

The objective is returning both the successful fetched data in 'data' field and error message for failed field in 'errors' field.
I have checked this: [How to return both error and data in a graphql resolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778096/how-to-return-both-error-and-data-in-a-graphql-resolver)
If I set a field that throw one error or exception intentionally, I will only get 'errors' field at last(Like the picture above).

In addition, many websites like this:https://itnext.io/the-definitive-guide-to-handling-graphql-errors-e0c58b52b5e1 suggest we should return partial result and error message, but in my case if I meet exception, only error message would be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our example application we have two top level queries

```
{
  onlyCake(msg: "cake")
  generateNumber
}
```

If I run this code this will return a random number and `onlyCake` returns the string `<3`. However if I modify the input of `onlyCake` to something that is not the string `cake` I will get an error. This is expected because the field `onlyCake` has a directive to implement this behavior.

https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/blob/2961b64d6e4cceb4034aec198d667e5f965decd2/example/src/main/kotlin/com/expedia/graphql/sample/directives/CakeOnlyDirectiveWiring.kt#L18-L19

[image: Screen Shot 2019-06-25 at 5 11 45 PM]

The question is though, if I want to return the data still for `generateNumber` can I do that and have both `errors` and `data` in the response?

---

The answer is it's possible but not with the current schema. The issue is that our schema for `onlyCake` and `generateNumber` are both non-nullable fields. So as a client if I see that there is a `data` field I should expect to see both there otherwise I would have a parsing issue in my code. This is why we can't have this behaviour with the schema as is. If you want to implement this behaviour, the schema developer needs to decide where they can return null for some response and modify the errors field appropriately with a `DataFetcherExceptionHandler`

Or the other option is that we support the behaviour in `graphql-java` to return a `DataFetcherResult<T>` instead of just `T` from the kotlin functions. See the section `Returning data and errors` here: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v13/execution/

I have created an issue to continue this discussion with other team members: https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/issues/244